# LibGDX- Unexpected computing by libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

i recently had problems of FPS drop (~40 FPS), and when i searched where it was. I saw that it wasnt me, all my calculation were done in 7 ms which is far from the 16 ms limit.

This is the code i used :

```
long time = 0;
public void render(float delta)
{
    System.out.println("since last frame : " +( System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Rendering...

    System.out.println("render : " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
}
```

And my time "since last frame" was around 22 ms and my "render" was around 7 ms. I just don't understand what libgdx is doing during thoses 15 ms, or if it is my fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LibGDX is swapping the back and front buffer. This requires to wait for the GPU to finish rendering. So whatever you've told the GPU to do in `render()` which hasn't finished yet will still have to finish before the next call to the `render()` method can be made.

CPU and GPU operate in parallel. e.g. when you call `SpriteBatch#end()` it will almost return immediatly (if it doesn't have to wait for something else to complete first). But that doesn't mean that it is actually rendered. It only means that it has *instructed* the GPU to render whatever you've added to the batch using e.g. the `draw(...)` method.

This rendering happens onto the backbuffer, which is an off-screen image. When your `render()` method completes this backbuffer is swapped with the frontbuffer, so that the screen displays whatever you've rendered in your `render()` method. It can only swap these buffers if the GPU completed executed your instructions and thus it needs to wait if it hasn't completed yet.

Comment: Well thank you, i think this is the problem, because it happens when my GPU is used by another software. Then i think i can't do anything, i can only try to do less spritebatch calls. Also, i'm impressed how fast and precise your answer was.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do a heap dump to check if and where you might have a memory leak. I guess you forgot to dispose some objects (`Stage` or `SpriteBatch` are often forgotten to dispose).

Comment: Oh yeah, i don't have any memory leak, i checked that.

Comment: Disposing is used to tell libGDX that it can throw away the instance. If you don't do this, your app will get slower and slower as you are collecting a lot of unused instances in your memory.

Comment: But i never make new instance of sprite batches, i have only one.

Comment: Also, it is slow even at the beginning, it is clearly not a memory leak.

Comment: Then this is not the problem. I just saw this in the past that people created many instances of SpriteBatch (sometimes even in the render method itself), and never disposed them. I would suggest you to dispose it when your app is closed anyway.

Comment: Okay ^^ Thanks anyway, it could have been that, but i already have enough experience with libgdx not to create a SpriteBatch every render call. (But i admit, i dit it in the beginning)

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to make sure :) I did it too ;-)